# How to ensure numbers read as string when using pandas to read excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column 'answer' in excel sheet which are numbers, and when read by pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_names)
```

The numbers are read as floats:

```
10.0
2.0
1.0
```

In the original sheet, they are just:

```
10
2
1
```

I used the apply function to convert the answer column to strings, they are indeed strings, but they are still string in float format, namely, looking like float numbers.

```
answer_data = sheet_data['answer'].apply(str).tolist()
```

How can I ensure the column can be read as string initially:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_names)
```

Comment: use the `dtype` parameter: `df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_names, dtype={'answer': str})`

Comment: Alternatively you can use converters argument 
```pd.read_excel(my_file, converters = {my_str_column: str})
```

Comment: @DavidErickson it's cool!

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than one column to convert, then you use the following code.

```py
pd.read_csv(
    csv_filepath,
    converters = {str_col1: str,
                  str_col2: str,
                  str_col3:str,
                  str_col4:str}
)
```